# How to repair "order by" after union of 2 selects from 1 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a dropDownList on my form, where i need to have union of values from 2 colums of table [ost].

Type of this columns is currency.
I have russian version of access, default value of curency in "rur" and i need "uah".
I need to change format and save "order by".

I use this query:

```
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum1] ,'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost) 
Union 
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum2],'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Can you supply a few items of sample data that make it clear?

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with it, so it's a bit hard to guess how to repair it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to sort by the original value, then you have to include that in the result:

```
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum1] ,'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."'), [Sum1] FROM ost) 
Union 
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum2],'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."'), [Sum2] FROM ost)
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get what you want. If you need to order afterwards:

I'm not sure if you need a table alias, but wouldn't an outer `SELECT` work?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum1] ,'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost) 
    UNION
    (SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum2],'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost)
)
ORDER BY 1
```

If you need to preserve order, doesn't this simple query work?

```
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum1] ,'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost ORDER BY 1)
UNION
(SELECT distinct FORMAT([Sum2],'# ##0.00" uah.";-# ##0.00" uah."') FROM ost ORDER BY 1)
```

But there's always "one more problem" with any SQL I write, so please check if it actually fulfills the requirements.

Comment: That does the same thing as the original query, as the ordering is applied after the union.